# Laptop randomly going in hibernate

Tags: laptop

I have an Asus ROG G751JT laptop, and a few days ago my battery has died. The problem that I am encountering is that my laptop randomly goes to sleep after a few minutes of use even when plugged in. I have formated both my SSD (that I have my OS on ) and my other HDD and the problem persists. The intersting thing is that when I reinstall the OS ( Windows 10 ) the laptop is working fine untill I unplug it , after I unplug it the hibernate thing starts happening. I have tried turning hibernate completely off but if I do that the laptop just shuts down instead of hibernating. I will replace the battery but in the meantime is there anything that I can do so I don't have to install the OS a few times a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hibernates (or shutdowns in the case hibernation is disabled) simply because it's set to hibernate / shutdown when the battery level is under some threshold. And your battery is probably so worn out, that it's constantly under that threshold.

You can try to open the *Power Options* control panel applet, click on *Change plan setting* on the plan you're using, then *Change advanced power settings* and locate the *Battery* node in the list tree. There you can change the thresholds and actions which are performed when those thresholds are reached (hibernation / shutdown etc.).

Comment: It worked, thank you! I still don't understand why the laptop wouldn't have that problem after I reinstalled Windows, it's quite weird.

Comment: That's just a consequence I would say. Anyway, I would never reinstall the operating system (even Windows) to "fix" any issue. I usually have single installation for 5 or more years.